# Multiple xmlhttprequest on a page

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am having an error when using new `XMLHttpRequest()` for the second time in JavaScript code called from textbox event on page.
My JavaScript finds suggestions for text entry from the SQL to do that I use `xmlhttprequest`, it does fine when it is the first time but when I keep typing in the text box I receive:

> "typeerror: xmlhttprequest not a costructor"

(this error happens only in Firefox)

This is my code:

```
function fnNull() { }; 
function changeofstate(){
   if (XMLHttpRequest.readyState == 4) 
           {
whatever ;

}
 XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = fnNull();
}
function whentextchange(){
   var WebURL = "the url here ";
         XMLHttpRequest = CreateXmlHttpObject(changeOfState);
         XMLHttpRequest.open("GET", WebURL, true);
         XMLHttpRequest.send(null);
         XMLHttpRequestt.abort();
   }


}

function CreateXmlHttpObject(handler) {    
       var objXmlHttpReq = null;
       var Req = null;

                   if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera")>=0)
                   {                  
                   return ;
                  }
                  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")>=0)
                  { 
                   var strName="Msxml2.XMLHTTP";
                   if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 5.5")>=0)
                   {
                   strName="Microsoft.XMLHTTP";
                   } 
                  try
                   {
                     
                   objXmlHttpReq=new ActiveXObject(strName);
                   objXmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = handler;
                 
                   return objXmlHttpReq;
                  } 
                  catch(e)
                  {                
                   return ;
                   } 
                   }
                   if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mozilla") >= 0) {
                     try
                   {
                            if (Req == null) {
                          Req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                       }
                       
                             Req.onload = handler;
                           Req.onerror = handler;
                           return Req;
                
                       }
                       catch (e) {
                           alert(e);
                       alert(Req.responseText)
                           alert(e);
                           return;
                       } 
                   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should name your request object something else than XMLHttpRequest. It might override the XMLHttpRequest object in the browser. Thus giving you the error.

```
XMLHttpRequest = CreateXmlHttpObject(changeOfState);
```

Assigning XMLHttpRequest variable like this is actually using global scope. You should use var and another variable name

```
var req = CreateXmlHttpObject(changeOfState);
```

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: well I named it Req, is that what you mean?

Comment: also when i look in the error console, i see several of this logs. uncaught exception index or size is negative or greater then the allowed amount code:1 nsresult:"0x80530001 ns error dom index size error

Comment: XMLHttpRequest = CreateXmlHttpObject(changeOfState); should be var req = CreateXmlHttpObject(changeOfState);